# How can I export tables from Oracle AppEx (online version) to my computer?

Tags: sql, oracle, project, oracle-apex-5

Hy there!
First of all: I'm a completely noob so ... bear with me. 
 
I have this database highschool project on **Oracle AppEx** (online version) and my question is: how can I make all those tables an SQL Script or how can I export those table into an offline version?

[image]

... I must put them on a CD ... that's why I'm asking this stupid question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SqlWorkshop** -> **Utilities** -> **Generate DDL**
Use save script as file and then through wizard select your own tables.